# Unit test an WF activity that connects to an database

Tags: c#, .net, database, unit-testing, workflow-foundation

I have a WF activity that takes in a server name, database name as arguments and connects to a database to fetch some data.

I need to unit test this activity, but I need some ideas... since I only have the server and database name. usually the mocking frameworks create the actual data objects and not the "server" and "database".

Any ideas?

Thanks